# Error Files no found after "grunt serve:dist"

Tags: angularjs

I only add two more files two more files at the end to scripts/Auth/authCtrl.js and scripts/Auth/authService.js

[image]

and all works on development but it says is missing all those files when running the dist. Please help me fins whats wrong thanks

[BUG LINK](https://tools.brandinstitute.com/facebookTools/bug.jpg)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the problem, it turns out that when I create the distribution application with grunt server:dist the index file was being copy over as it its and it did not have any reference of the minified files; so I replace all the script links for the ones minified only and all works now.

```
<script src="scripts/vendor.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/ui.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
```

instead of

```
   <!-- build:js scripts/vendor.js -->
    <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/underscore/underscore.js"></script>    
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <!-- endbuild -->

    <!-- build:js scripts/ui.js -->      
    <script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/jquery-spinner/dist/jquery.spinner.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/seiyria-bootstrap-slider/dist/bootstrap-slider.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/jquery-steps/build/jquery.steps.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/toastr/toastr.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap-file-input/bootstrap.file-input.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/jquery.slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/holderjs/holder.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/raphael/raphael-min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/morris.js/morris.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/vendors/jquery.sparkline.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/flot/jquery.flot.resize.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/flot/jquery.flot.pie.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/flot/jquery.flot.stack.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/flot.tooltip/js/jquery.flot.tooltip.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/flot/jquery.flot.time.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/gauge.js/dist/gauge.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/jquery.easy-pie-chart/dist/angular.easypiechart.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-wizard/dist/angular-wizard.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/textAngular/dist/textAngular-rangy.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/textAngular/dist/textAngular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/textAngular/dist/textAngular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-local-storage/dist/angular-local-storage.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/vendors/skycons.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-loading-bar/build/loading-bar.min.js"></script>
    <!-- endbuild -->

    <!-- build:js({.tmp,client}) scripts/app.js -->
    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/shared/main.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/shared/directives.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/shared/localize.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/UI/UICtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/UI/UIDirective.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/UI/UIService.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/Form/FormDirective.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/Form/FormCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/Form/FormValidation.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/Table/TableCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/Task/Task.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/Chart/ChartCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/Chart/ChartDirective.js"></script>     
    <script src="scripts/Auth/authCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/Auth/authService.js"></script>
    <!-- endbuild -->
```